# cursor blinks but can't type in input form

Tags: html

Ok guys I've looked at like 7 other questions on here that have similar symptoms but do not describe my issue.

My issue is this:

I have a text input. When I click on it, I see the cursor, but I cannot type. This happens in all browsers.

I can copy and paste data inside, and when I submit it it passes just fine.

Everything about this form field input works EXCEPT the ability to actually type in it.

One thing to add is that I have it working on a different page and everything is fine, which leads me to believe there is something going on with this page. I'm not getting any console errors or anything that looks funny with dev tools.

Does anyone have any speculation on what could be happening?

Comment: can you put your page url so i can check wht's going wrong.

Comment: i've seen improperly loaded javascript cause this issue before. Are you using any JS? If you could, provide a jsFiddle, some code or a link

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys thanks for responding but I have found the issue. The code that was ruining everything was this:

```
jQuery('.url').keypress(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var key = e.which;
     if (key == 13) // the enter key code
        {  
           jQuery('.main').trigger('click');
        }
});
```

I changed the first line to:

```
jQuery('.url').keyup(function(e) {
```

and it worked.